# Output of R script is hidden in the console

Tags: r, console, output

```
z <- 5
count <- 0
while(z > 0 && z < 10){
    X=rbinom(1,1, 0.5)
    if(X == 1)
    {
        z <- z+1
    } 
    else if(X == 0)
    {
        z <- z-1
    }
    count <- count+1
    }
print(count)
```

Hi, this is my R script. I was wondering why when I type in:

> source ('filename.R')

,there is no output in the console. But when I run another R script:

```
x <- 1:10
print(x)
```

it prints to the console.

I'm using Rx64 3.0.2. Thank you.

Comment: It works fine on my machine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using: `?source`

```
# This will echo all input and not truncate 150+ character lines..
source("filename.R", echo=TRUE,max.deparse.length=10000, continue.echo = getOption("continue"))
```

Comment: `X=rbinom(1,1, 0.5)` will generate different random numbers each time you submit. so set the seed - within the while loop

Answer (score 0):

To amplify Prasanna's answer, here's the help file info:

> echo   logical; if TRUE, each expression is printed after parsing,
>   before evaluation.
>
> print.eval     logical; if TRUE, the result of eval(i) is printed for
>   each expression i; defaults to the value of echo.

Since the default value is `echo=FALSE`, you see nothing.  This is a **good** default, since most of the time `source` is used to load functions rather than execute scripts, and people generally :-)  don't want the function source splattered all over the console.